# View contents of PostgreSQL backup

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am running scheduled backups on my Heroku application (rails 4). I downloaded the backup that ran last night and I'd like to view the contents of the file. When I open it in textedit, I can see the tables but then it's just a mix of characters and letters.

I have scheduled backups running every evening on my Heroku PG db so I just had to download the backup from the previous day. To download the backup I ran:

```
heroku pg:backups public-url --app foobar
```

I then visited the AWS S3 link provided by Heroku and downloaded the file onto my computer.

How would I go about either viewing the contents of the backup in terminal or any other GUI without restoring the backup into my Heroku application?

Comment: What is the **exact** command you used to take the backup? (**Edit** your question, don't post additional information as comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated my question with the information you asked for.